# Deleted authorized_keys from EC2 but still have PPK file and I'm connected

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I just deleted my full ec2-user/.ssh/ folder and I want to recover the keys so I can access my EC2 server without stopping and starting it.

I have on my computer a PPK file that has something like "Private-Lines" so I'm guessing it has both private and public key... I've tried a lot of things without success so, what are the step by step instructions to recover my keys to the server using this PPK key?

I'm still connect via SSH :)

Comment: Why not generate a new key with ssh-keygen, add the public part to your server's authorized_keys so you're not locked out when the network dies unexpectedly?

Comment: And what if I disconnect without realizing that? How will I recover?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, this is really easy:

1. Open puttygen
2. Click Load and Load PPK file
3. Copy the key that is on the first textarea (public key for pasting...)
4. In the linux server create `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and paste the key
5. `chmod 700 ~/.ssh`
6. `chmod 600 ~/authorized_keys`